# Trouble creating GAE entity

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, typeerror, keyword-argument

I get the following error message when I try to submit a new entity in GAE.

```
File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Web Apps\legalstudybuddy\main.py", line 179, in post
    c = Courses(user=user, title=title)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

Here is my Python code:

```
class Courses(db.Model):
    user = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

class Courses(Handler):
    def get(self, courses="", title="", signup_username="", login_logout=""):

        if not self.user:
            self.redirect('/login')

        user = str(self.read_secure_cookie('user_id'))
        courses = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * from Courses  WHERE user = :user ORDER BY created DESC', user=user)

        signup_username, login_logout = self.user_check()

        self.render('courses.html', courses=courses,
                    title=title,
                    signup_username=signup_username,
                    login_logout=login_logout)

    def post(self):
        if not self.user:
            self.redirect('/login')

        user = str(self.read_secure_cookie('user_id'))
        title = self.request.get('title')

        if title:
            c = Courses(user=user, title=title)
            c.put()

        self.redirect('/courses')
```

The unexpected keyword argument is from creating the entity not from the django template. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining `Courses` twice. Once as the model:

```
class Courses(db.Model):
    user = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

But also as the handler:

```
class Courses(Handler):
    # code
```

Since you define the handler second, that is what is stored as `Courses` in the current namespace. For example:

```
In [1]: class Courses(object):
   ...:     a = 'First Courses'
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [2]: class Courses(object):
   ...:     a = 'Second Courses'
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [3]: Courses.a
Out[3]: 'Second Courses'
```

I would suggest changing the name of the handler so that you don't get the conflict you are getting now (where when you call `Courses(user=user)`, it is trying to call the handler instead of the model).

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much for the speedy reply.

Comment: @user1927856 No problem at all, definitely an easy mistake to make. Good luck with everything!